# Error during library import in Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, svn, svn-hooks

I am trying to configure svn hook for email notification using mailer.py script from apache, but it always crash on import of svn libs. I try two ways of installing svn and python. I try to install everything manually using command line and use CollableNet installer that have preinstalled Python and all libs I need but result is the same.

Now I try to import one library from hole package that I need using python in command line and I have such response:

```
>>> import svn.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named svn.core
```

I try to fix it using:

1) `import sys; sys.path.append("C:\csvn\lib\svn-python\svn")`

and

2) `C:\csvn\lib\svn-python\svn>python "\__init__.py" install`

But it didn't help.
For now I have no package with setup.py to install it.

I spend a lot of time on this task, and going crazy a little). Please give me any suggestion how to fix it.

Comment: Salute to you! It works. Thanx a lot!!!! ! ! Winterfall is the man)

Comment: glad it worked, do you add the py file to the path before, and it failed to import?

Comment: I didn't add *.py before. In this package is only *.pyc files. Should I add each file separately? I just remove "\svn" from sys.path.append command. Now I try to import 2 libraries from package in command line and have no error. But mailer.py still fails. Maybe restart will help. I hope. And still I didnt understand why it work if there is no __init__ file in "svn-python" directory. How python know that it's package?

Comment: I'm not clear about that either, you may try to google some document of the lib you use, may be a good help.